# LOOKUPVALUE Power Pivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

Estoy montando una tabla dinámica para calcular los consumos de combustible de una flota.
La tabla tiene estos campos:

```
FECHA  CUAENTAKILOMETROS  VEHICULO  CANTIDAD(L)
```

Para calcular el consumo medido en Lts/100Kmts necesito crear unas medidas que pueda añadir a la tabla dinámica y que funcionen para cada vehículo. Son:
`KmMAX:=CALCULATE(MAX([CUENTAKILÓMETROS]))` / Que me devuelve el dato de marcador más alto de cada vehículo.

`KmMIN:=CALCULATE(MIN([CUENTAKILÓMETROS]))` / Que me devuelve el dato de marcador más bajo de cada vehículo.

`KmtsRecorridos:=[KmMAX]-[KmMIN]` / Que me devuelve los Kmts recorridos en el periodo filtrado.

`Sum_Lts:=CALCULATE(SUM([CANTIDAD (L)]))` / Que me devuelve la cantidad de litros consumidos en el periodo filtrado por cada vehículo.

Hasta aquí todo bien. Pero el problema es que para calcular el consumo, necesito obtener el campo de `CANDIDAD (L)` que corresponde al registro de la tabla en el que se cumple la condición de que el `CUENTAKILOMETROS` corresponde al mínimo, puesto la formula para el cálculo sería:

```
Consumo= (Sum_Lits - Lits_echados_KmsMIN ) / KmtsRecorridos
```

La medida para `Lits_echados_KmtsMIN` la intento obtener así:

```
LtsLKmtsMIN:=LOOKUPVALUE([CANTIDAD (L)];[CUENTAKILÓMETROS];[KmMIN])
```

Pero me devuelve un error cuando en el modelo hay mas un registro con el mismo valor.

¿Como podría afrontar este cálculo?
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Creo que el error puede venir de la referencia al campo `[CANTIDAD (L)]`pues la fórmula espera el nombre del campo en el formato `Tabla[Campo]`. Intenta hacer `LtsLKmtsMIN:=LOOKUPVALUE(NOMBRETABLA[CANTIDAD (L)];[CUENTAKILÓMETROS];[KmMIN])`

Comment: No es ese el problema. El problema radica en que [LtsLKmtsMIN:=LOOKUPVALUE([CANTIDAD (L)];[CUENTAKILÓMETROS];[KmMIN])] falla cuando en la tabla existen registros con el mismo dato para dos vehículos distintos. Por ejemplo si el vehículo A tiene 100 kmts y el B tambien tiene un registro con 100 kmts, la formula devuelve error